# How can I combine multiple CSV files into one with Python and Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have looked at many posts on the same topic, but my situation is a little different from others so I would like some advice on how to deal with it. Right now I have a lot of CSV files with many different and extra columns, and I want to combine them all into one master file.

I have created one master CSV file that has all the column headers that I will need, the file only has headers and does not have any data.

I want to merge the rest of the CSV files into this master CSV file where I will only take in the columns with headers that exist in the master CSV file (they have extra columns that I do not need).

For example, master file has header 1 2 3 4 5 and this other csv file has header 2 3 4 5 6 7. I want the other csv file's column 2 3 4 5 fill into the empty spaces of the master file's column 2 3 4 5 and not include column 6 7.

```
    for entry in os.scandir(dir):
        if(entry.name.endswith(".csv")):
            print(dir+entry.name +" :\t Start")
```

That is the loop I'm using to read through a folder of CSV files and merging them one by one with the master file.

```
if pd.Series(h0).isin(df.columns).all():
    master_file.merge(df, how='left')
    master_file.to_csv("D:\\Desktop\\Master File.csv", index=False)
```

This is one of the filtering steps I'm using. h0 is a list of column headers that I would like included. I have called read_csv on both master_file and df so they are both dataframes right now, but the merging does nothing. What should I do? Thanks!

EDIT: Thank you for all the advice and help! I will look at all of them tomorrow! Again, thanks!

Comment: This is the doc for `merge`, yes? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Answer (score 0):

You can find an intersection of column names of a `sub.csv` with the `master.csv` using set operator & and combine two pandas dataframes using `pandas.concat` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
if __name__ == '__main__':
    master_df = pd.read_csv("data/master.csv")
    dfs = [master_df]
    for a_path in glob.iglob("data/csvs/*.csv", recursive=True):
        a_df = pd.read_csv(a_path)
        intersect_cols = set(a_df.columns.values) & set(master_df.columns.values)
        master_df = pd.concat([master_df, a_df[intersect_cols]], axis=0)
    print(master_df)
```

master.csv:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

sub1.csv:

```
2,3,4,5,6,7
2,3,4,5,6,7
2,3,4,5,6,7
```

sub2.csv

```
2,3,4,5,6,7
7,6,5,4,3,2
7,6,5,4,3,2
```

Result:

```
     1  2  3  4  5
0  NaN  7  6  5  4
1  NaN  7  6  5  4
0  NaN  2  3  4  5
1  NaN  2  3  4  5
```

After getting a combined dataframe, you can save it to a csv using `dataframe.to_csv`.